# Unable to build JNI for Signal Protocol - 'Permission denied' issue

Tags: android, android-ndk, rust-cargo

I need to build [this Signal Protocol](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal) for Android.

I've followed the instructions in Readme. I am running the command:

```
bash build_jni.sh android
```

I get the error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `boring-sys v3.1.0 (https://github.com/signalapp/boring?branch=libsignal#8245063a)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/mnt/c/Users/Zakwan/libsignal/target/release/build/boring-sys-25b8d88d9fdb8a76/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BORING_BSSL_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BORING_BSSL_INCLUDE_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BORING_BSSL_SOURCE_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BORING_SSL_PRECOMPILED_BCM_O
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=BORINGSSL_BUILD_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /home/zakwan/.cargo/git/checkouts/boring-b37daebd62069023/8245063/boring-sys/build.rs:153:76:
  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Operation not permitted (os error 1)" }
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

and

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `pqcrypto-internals v0.2.5`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/mnt/c/Users/Zakwan/libsignal/target/release/build/pqcrypto-internals-6c45ebe961ca6957/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:includepath=/home/zakwan/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pqcrypto-internals-0.2.5/include
  TARGET = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("s")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64-linux-android
  CC_aarch64-linux-android = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64_linux_android
  CC_aarch64_linux_android = Some("/mnt/c/Users/Zakwan/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.2.11394342/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin//aarch64-linux-android21-clang")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64-linux-android
  CFLAGS_aarch64-linux-android = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64_linux_android
  CFLAGS_aarch64_linux_android = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CFLAGS
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = Some("-DOPENSSL_SMALL -flto=full ")
  running: "/mnt/c/Users/Zakwan/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.2.11394342/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin//aarch64-linux-android21-clang" "-Os" "-DANDROID" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-DOPENSSL_SMALL" "-flto=full" "-I" "/home/zakwan/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pqcrypto-internals-0.2.5/include" "-o" "/mnt/c/Users/Zakwan/libsignal/target/aarch64-linux-android/release/build/pqcrypto-internals-224fe427a56bee64/out/cfiles/fips202.o" "-c" "cfiles/fips202.c"
  cargo:warning=error: unable to open output file '/mnt/c/Users/Zakwan/libsignal/target/aarch64-linux-android/release/build/pqcrypto-internals-224fe427a56bee64/out/cfiles/fips202.o': 'Permission denied'

  cargo:warning=1 error generated.
```

I looked into the folder: `/mnt/c/Users/Zakwan/libsignal/target/aarch64-linux-android/release/build/pqcrypto-internals-224fe427a56bee64/out` but there is no cfiles folder nor .o files.

Any help is much appreciated as I spent two days now on this without avail.

Many thanks

I am running Android Studio in Windows, and it seems there the following task for the build:

```
task makeJniLibraries(type:Exec) {
  group 'Rust'
  description 'Build the JNI libraries for Android'

  // Explicitly specify 'bash' for Windows compatibility.
  commandLine 'bash', '../build_jni.sh', 'android'
  environment 'ANDROID_NDK_HOME', android.ndkDirectory
}
```

I installed Android NDK, and configured the correct ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable. I installed ubuntu for Windows to be able to run the above bash command to run the .sh script.

Comment: May be a bug in the build system. Have you tried to manually create the `cfiles` folder so that the build file can create .o files in it?